# Page Blob download with Azure java SDK does not download the complete Blob

Tags: azure-java-sdk

Trying to download a page blob of size 2 GB using java sdk and it fails with Storage exception because the file size downloaded does not match the actual file size

On multiple tries the same result is seen, although there is slight change in the downloaded file size. Setting timeout to maximum value also does not help. 
Also, when I download the same vhd using the Azure portal, I see that the download completes but only partially. It is usually comparable to the one downloaded with SDK.

In the SDK code, I can see HTTpUrlConnection is being used. Could that be a problem ? The same code on a Windows machine has similar results but only the downloaded file is few more MB's in size but not complete.

Any thoughts on how to get it working ?

The code snippet used is

```
URI blobEndpoint = null;
String uriString = "http://" + "sorageaccount" + ".blob.core.windows.net";
blobEndpoint = new URI(uriString);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = new CloudBlobClient(blobEndpoint,
            new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey("abcd", "passed"));
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference(Constants.STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME);
            CloudPageBlob pageBlob = container.getPageBlobReference("http://abcd.blob.core.windows.net/sc/someimg.vhd");
System.out.println("Page Blob Name: " + pageBlob.getName());

OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("/Users/myself/Downloads/TestDownload.vhd"));
System.out.println("Starting download now ... ");
BlobRequestOptions options = new BlobRequestOptions();
options.setUseTransactionalContentMD5(true);
options.setStoreBlobContentMD5 (true); // Set full blob level MD5
options.setTimeoutIntervalInMs(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
options.setRetryPolicyFactory(new RetryLinearRetry());

pageBlob.download(outStream, null, options, null);
        outStream.close();
```